# How can I customize STAssertEquals output for C++ classes and structs?

Tags: c++, xcode, unit-testing, ocunit

I'm using OCUnit to write test cases in XCode 4.3.2. I would like to compare C++ classes and structures with `STAssertEquals`, but unfortunately `STAssertEquals` prints object references by default when the test fails.

How can I customize the output from `STAssertEquals` for user-defined types in C++?

I tried to implement `operator<<` on `std::ostream` for my objects—`std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const MyObject& obj);`—but that doesn't appear to change the output.

Answer (score 0):

Add code that wraps your C++ class or struct in an Objective-C object. Then implement an `-isEqual:` method that checks for equality.